# Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in code igniter model working fine in localhost

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, fatal-error

this my model code:

```
function get_ads($page=0, $type, $limit=1, $order=' order by rand()') { 
    if ($page === 0) {
        $page = $this->get_adpage(); 
        $qry = "select * from tbl_ads ";
        $qry .= " where status=1 and pages like '%".$page. "%'";
        $qry .= " and type = ".intval($type);
        $qry .= $order;
        $qry .= intval($limit) > 1 ? " limit 0,".$limit : " limit 0,1";   
        $results = $this->db->query($qry)->result(); return $results;}
     }
}
```

Query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_ads WHERE STATUS=1 AND pages LIKE '%1%' AND TYPE = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1`
```

Controller code is

```
function get_ads(){
    $this->main_model->get_ads(14,2,1);
}
```

Its working fine local when uploading to server showing fatal error some times but some times its working fine.

Thanks for your help

Comment: submit you model  and controller code

Comment: The above code is model  here  my controller code 
function get_ads(){$this->main_model->get_ads(14,2,1);}
Model:
function get_ads($page=0,$type,$limit=1,$order=' order by rand()')
 {
  if($page===0)
   $page = $this->get_adpage();
  $qry = "select * from tbl_ads ";
  $qry .= " where status=1 and pages like '%".$page. "%'";
  $qry .= " and type = ".intval($type);
  $qry .= $order;
  $qry .= intval($limit) > 1 ? " limit 0,".$limit : " limit 0,1";
  $results = $this->db->query($qry)->result(); 
return $results;}

Comment: please edit your question put you code in your question not in a comment

Comment: Are you sure? Your Model function get_ads has too many } AND if you set $pages to anything other than 0 that function will return null.

Comment: yeah, its working fine  in local... and also  working some times in server.  no problem since one  year . we updated  some other functions in model before one week, then this error occurred, we replaced with backup file but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution 
$this->db->query($qry)->result() in this instead of result() result_array()  for multiple rows  or row_array() for single row of result did the trick